# using shell script to grep string between string a and string b

Tags: regex, shell, grep

For example:
I have a txt file  like :

text("hello")
text("world")
text("once")
text("again")

```
Aim to replace 
hello  with string_1,
world with string_2,
once with string_3,
again  with string_4,
```

How to write the script?

Comment: `grep` is not useful for this.  Read up no `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 's/hello/string_1/g;s/world/string_2/g;s/once/string_3/g;s/again/string_4/g' your_file;
```

the above command will do inplace replacement.if you want the ouput to console,then,
remove "`i`".

another way is :

```
sed -e 's/hello/string_1/g;s/world/string_2/g;s/once/string_3/g;s/again/string_4/g' your_file
```

awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/hello/,"string_1");gsub(/world/,"string_2");gsub(/once/,"string_3");gsub(/again/,"string_4");print}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice technique is to use a dictionary of replacement strings.  Something like:

```
perl -pe '%x=(
    "hello" => "string_1",
    "world" => "string_2", 
    "once" => "string_3",
    "again" => "string_4",
    );
    s/$k/$v/g while( $k, $v ) = each %x' input-file
```